# Bootstrap code not reporting bias or standard error

Tags: r, regression, statistics-bootstrap

I wrote this code in R:

```
library(boot)

bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample 
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)
 return(coef(fit)) 
}
results <- boot(data=z, statistic=bs, 
 R=1000, formula=z[,1]~z[,2])
```

I'm trying to do random x -resampling using for data a dataframe that contains my response and my predictor however my results return without bias and without std.

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
      original  bias    std. error
t1* 83.5466254       0           0
t2* -0.6360426       0           0
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula is incorrect. When you use `z[,1]~z[,2]` you are literally specifying a formula that has the first column of `z` as the response and the second column of `z` as the independent variables. Note that `z` never changes. It's the `data=` parameter that's changing. Furthernore, the formula syntax does not work with positional indexes like that. You need to use variable names. Here's some sample data

```
z <- data.frame(a=runif(50), b=runif(50))
```

Note how this doesn't work

```
results <- boot(data=z, statistic=bs, 
 R=10, formula=z[,1]~z[,2])
results

# Bootstrap Statistics :
#       original  bias    std. error
# t1* 0.45221233       0           0
# t2* 0.08818014       0           0
```

it's just retuning the same values over and over again which are the same as when you use the fill data set

```
lm(a~b, z)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            b  
#     0.45221      0.08818
```

What you want is

```
results <- boot(data=z, statistic=bs, 
 R=10, formula=a~b)
results

# Bootstrap Statistics :
#       original      bias    std. error
# t1* 0.45221233  0.01024794  0.08853861
# t2* 0.08818014 -0.01546608  0.16376128
```

This allows for the `boot` function to pass in a different dataset each time and since the literal vector values aren't included in the formula that specially refer to the `z` data.frame, you'll get updated values.